# Using an escaped (magic) character as boundary in a character range in Lua patterns

Tags: lua, lua-patterns

The [Lua manual](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#5.4) in section 6.4.1 on Lua Patterns states

> A character class is used to represent a set of characters. The
>   following combinations are allowed in describing a character class:
>
> - `x`: (where `x` is not one of the magic characters `^$()%.[]*+-?`) represents the character x itself.
> - `.`: (a dot) represents all characters.
> - `%a`: represents all letters.
> - `%c`: represents all control characters.
> - `%d`: represents all digits.
> - `%g`: represents all printable characters except space.
> - `%l`: represents all lowercase letters.
> - `%p`: represents all punctuation characters.
> - `%s`: represents all space characters.
> - `%u`: represents all uppercase letters.
> - `%w`: represents all alphanumeric characters.
> - `%x`: represents all hexadecimal digits.
> - `%`x: (where x is any non-alphanumeric character) represents the character x. This is the standard way to escape the magic characters.
>     Any non-alphanumeric character (including all punctuation characters,
>     even the non-magical) can be preceded by a `%` when used to represent
>     itself in a pattern.
> - `[set]`: represents the class which is the union of all characters in `set`. A range of characters can be specified by separating the end
>     characters of the range, in ascending order, with a `-`. All classes
>     `%x` described above can also be used as components in set. All other
>     characters in `set` represent themselves. For example, `[%w_]` (or
>     `[_%w]`) represents all alphanumeric characters plus the underscore,
>     `[0-7]` represents the octal digits, and `[0-7%l%-]` represents the
>     octal digits plus the lowercase letters plus the `-` character.
>
> You can put a closing square bracket in a set by positioning it as the
>   first character in the set. You can put a hyphen in a set by
>   positioning it as the first or the last character in the set. (You can
>   also use an escape for both cases.)
>
> **The interaction between ranges and classes is not defined. Therefore, patterns like [%a-z] or [a-%%] have no meaning.**
>
> `[^set]`: represents the complement of set, where set is interpreted
>   as above.
>
> For all classes represented by single letters (`%a`, `%c`, etc.), the
>   corresponding uppercase letter represents the complement of the class.
>   For instance, %S represents all non-space characters.
>
> The definitions of letter, space, and other character groups depend on
>   the current locale. In particular, the class `[a-z]` may not be
>   equivalent to `%l`.
>   <sub>(Highlighting and some formatting added by me)</sub>

So, since the *"interaction between ranges and classes is not defined."*, how do you create a character class `set` that starts and/or ends with a (magic) character that needs to be escaped?

For example,

```
[%%-c]
```

does not define a character class that ranges from `%` to `c` and includes all characters in-between but a set that consists only of the three characters `%`, `-`, and `c`.

Comment: This question came up recently in a closed and subsequently deleted post. However, I think this is an interesting question that deserves to be documented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The interaction between ranges and classes is not defined.

Obviously, this is not a hard and fast rule (of regex character sets in general) but a Lua implementation decision. While using shorthand characters in character sets/ranges work in some (most) regex flavors, it does not in all (like in Python's re module, [demo](https://regex101.com/r/uCdkGh/2)).

However, the second example is misleading:

> Therefore, patterns like [%a-z] or [a-%%] have no meaning.

While the first example is fine since `%a` is a shorthand class (that represents all letters) in a `set`, `[%a-z]` is undefined and will return `nil` if matched against a string.

## Escaped range characters in a `[set]`

In the second example, `[a-%%]`, `%%` simply defines an escaped % sign and not a shorthand character class. The superficial problem is, the range is **defined upsidedown**, from **high** to **low** (in reference to the [US ASCII](https://ascii.cl/) value of the characters `a` *61* and `%` *37*), e.g like an erroneous Lua pattern like `[f-a]`. If the set is defined in reverse order it [seems to work](https://ideone.com/KbkGPN): `[%%-a]` but all it does is matching the three individual characters instead of the range of characters between `%` and `a`; credit [cyclaminist](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9383219/cyclaminist)).

This could be considered a bug and, indeed, means it is not possible to create a range of characters in a `[set]` if one of the defining range characters need to be escaped.

## Possible Solution

Start the character range from the next character that does not need to be escaped - and then add the remaining escaped characters individually, e.g.

```
[%%&-a]
```

[Sample](https://ideone.com/M7T3UL):

```
for w in string.gmatch("%&*()-0Aa", "[%%&-a]") do
  print(w)
end
```

This is the answer I have found. Still, maybe somebody else has something better.